# How do I get all the unique permissions for a user in sharepoint?

Tags: powershell, permissions, sharepoint-permissions

```
$groupArr = @()
$roleArr = @()    
$acct = Get-SPUser -Web $web -Identity $username

foreach ($role in $acct.roles)
{
    $roleArr += $role
}
foreach ($group in $acct.groups)
{
    $groupArr += $group
}
```

The code above works well and gives me an array for all role and group objects for a specific user.

The problem is this doesn't give unique permissions to items, groups and lists. I want and array of those unique permission objects too.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I know "roles" is obsolete. I'm working with what I got at the moment. Any and all advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found some code here: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/01/permission-report-for-specific-user.html

I didn't need to check for farm admin or web app policies. Nor did I need it to generate a CSV report.

So I altered it to only account for directly given permissions, unique permissions, and group membership permissions.

Best part is it returns an array of hash tables, or basically an array of dictionaries!

Here's my altered code....

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


Function GetUserAccessReport($WebAppURL, $SearchUser)
{
    $outputArr = @()
 
    #Write-host "Scanning Site Collections..."
    #Get All Site Collections of the WebApp
    $SiteCollections = Get-SPSite -WebApplication $WebAppURL -Limit All
     
    #Loop through all site collections
    foreach($Site in $SiteCollections)
    {
        #Write-host "Scanning Site Collection:" $site.Url
        #Check Whether the Search User is a Site Collection Administrator
        foreach($SiteCollAdmin in $Site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators)
        {
            if($SiteCollAdmin.LoginName -eq $SearchUser)
            {
                $dict = @{ "URL" = $($Site.RootWeb.Url); "Type" = "Site"; "Title" = $($Site.RootWeb.Title); "PermissionType" = "Site Collection Administrator"; "Permissions" = "Site Collection Administrator" }
                $outputArr += $dict
            }    
        }
    
     #Loop throuh all Sub Sites
        foreach($Web in $Site.AllWebs)
        {
            if($Web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True)
            {
                #Write-host "Scanning Site:" $Web.Url
     
                #Get all the users granted permissions to the list
                foreach($WebRoleAssignment in $Web.RoleAssignments )
                {
                    #Is it a User Account?
                    if($WebRoleAssignment.Member.userlogin)  
                    {
                        #Is the current user is the user we search for?
                        if($WebRoleAssignment.Member.LoginName -eq $SearchUser)
                        {
                            #Write-Host  $SearchUser has direct permissions to site $Web.Url
                            #Get the Permissions assigned to user
                            $WebUserPermissions=@()
                            foreach ($RoleDefinition  in $WebRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                            {
                                $WebUserPermissions += $RoleDefinition.Name +";"
                            }
                            #write-host "with these permissions: " $WebUserPermissions
           
                            #Send the Data to output array
                            $dict = @{ "URL" = $($Web.Url); "Type" = "Site";  "Title" = $($Web.Title); "permissionType" = "Direct Permission"; "Permissions" = $($WebUserPermissions) }
                            $outputArr += $dict
                        }
                    }
                    #Its a SharePoint Group, So search inside the group and check if the user is member of that group
                    else
                    {
                        foreach($user in $WebRoleAssignment.member.users)
                        {
                            #Check if the search users is member of the group
                            if($user.LoginName -eq $SearchUser)
                            {
                                #Write-Host  "$SearchUser is Member of " $WebRoleAssignment.Member.Name "Group"
                                #Get the Group's Permissions on site
                                $WebGroupPermissions=@()
                                foreach ($RoleDefinition  in $WebRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                                {
                                    $WebGroupPermissions += $RoleDefinition.Name +";"
                                }
                                #write-host "Group has these permissions: " $WebGroupPermissions
                
                                #Send the Data to output array
                                "URL `t type `t Title `t PermissionType `t Permissions"
                                $dict = @{ "URL" = $($Web.Url); "Type" =  "Site"; "Title" = $($Web.Title);  "PermissionType" = $($WebRoleAssignment.Member.Name); "Permissions" = $($WebGroupPermissions) }
                                $outputArr += $dict
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
      
            ###*****  Check Lists with Unique Permissions *******###
            foreach($List in $Web.lists)
            {
                if($List.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True -and ($List.Hidden -eq $false))
                {
                    #Write-host "Scanning List:" $List.RootFolder.Url
                    #Get all the users granted permissions to the list
                    foreach($ListRoleAssignment in $List.RoleAssignments )
                    {
                        #Is it a User Account?
                        if($ListRoleAssignment.Member.userlogin)  
                        {
                            #Is the current user is the user we search for?
                            if($ListRoleAssignment.Member.LoginName -eq $SearchUser)
                            {
                                #Write-Host  $SearchUser has direct permissions to List ($List.ParentWeb.Url)/($List.RootFolder.Url)
                                #Get the Permissions assigned to user
                                $ListUserPermissions=@()
                                foreach ($RoleDefinition  in $ListRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                                {
                                    $ListUserPermissions += $RoleDefinition.Name +";"
                                }
                                #write-host "with these permissions: " $ListUserPermissions
               
                                #Send the Data to Log file
                                $dict = @{ "URL" = $($List.ParentWeb.Url)+"/"+$($List.RootFolder.Url); "Type" = "List"; "Title" = $($List.Title); "PermissionType" = "Direct Permissions"; "Permissions" = $($ListUserPermissions) }
                                $outputArr += $dict
                            }
                        }
                        #Its a SharePoint Group, So search inside the group and check if the user is member of that group
                        else
                        {
                            foreach($user in $ListRoleAssignment.member.users)
                            {
                                if($user.LoginName -eq $SearchUser)
                                {
                                    #Write-Host  "$SearchUser is Member of " $ListRoleAssignment.Member.Name "Group"
                                    #Get the Group's Permissions on site
                                    $ListGroupPermissions=@()
                                    foreach ($RoleDefinition  in $ListRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                                    {
                                        $ListGroupPermissions += $RoleDefinition.Name +";"
                                    }
                                    #write-host "Group has these permissions: " $ListGroupPermissions
                
                                    #Send the Data to Log file
                                    $dict = @{ "URL" = $($Web.Url); "Type" = "Site"; "Title" = $($List.Title); "PermissionType" = $($ListRoleAssignment.Member.Name); "Permissions" =  $($ListGroupPermissions) }
                                    $outputArr += $dict
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $outputArr
    Write-host "`n Access Rights Report Generated!"
 }
```

Then you just call the function...

```
$Array = GetUserAccessReport 'https://venom.com' 'i:0ǵ.t|adfs|SpiderMan'
```

Hope this helps someone!! Happy Coding!